# How to forward unmapped requests to SPA in Spring 5

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, single-page-application

Prior to Spring 5, I could set up a request mapping like this to capture any requests that are not already mapped and don't have a dot (for assets like images, javascript etc) and forward them back to my Single Page App.

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}"])
fun forwardAngularPaths(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
    return "forward:/"
}
```

That syntax is no longer valid in Spring 5 due to the introduction of PathPatternParser.

https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc

I can't figure out how to achieve the same thing with the new PathPattern. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html), PathPattern only allows `**` at the end of a path, in order to eliminate ambiguity when comparing patterns for specificity. You can return to the previous behavior by setting

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher
```

Or if you are able to change the convention for your app, you can use the following PathPatternParser compatible request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/{path:(?!static$)[^.]*}/**")
fun forwardAngularPaths(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
    return "forward:/"
}
```

this excludes paths with a period in the first segment, such as `/index.html`, as well as all paths where the first segment is `/static/`. If there are additional routes to exclude (for instance, any websocket endpoints added in `registerStompEndpoints` should be excluded from this mapping) you can update the negative lookahead group from `(?!static$)` to, for example, `(?!js$|css$)` to exclude paths starting with either `/js/` or `/css/` instead.